# Uploading file using Spring REST API

Tags: spring, rest, file-upload

I have my controller like this, i am using POSTMAN REST client for upload pdf file. setting content-type: multipart/form-data;boundary=randomBoundaryNotInAnyOfParts
It is creating the file but not writing anything in it. Am i missing something here?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String upload(HttpServletRequest request) {


InputStream is = null;
OutputStream out = null; 
try {

is = request.getInputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\tmp\\upload.txt"));
out.write(b);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally{

try{
if(out != null){
out.close();
}
if(is != null){
is.close();
}
}catch(IOException io){
io.printStackTrace();
}

}
return null;
}
```

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Your byte[] is empty hence it is writing nothing in the file. Get content of the request into the byte[] and then write it into file.

Or you can use BufferedWriter also it is more fast.

Thanks,
Brijesh